# something which improves us intellectually & morally

Tags: single-word-requests

I need to find a word that conveys "something which improves us intellectually & morally".

Comment: Please share any research you have done. If you do that, it's unlikely this question will be closed for lack of research. Could you at the very least provide the context for this word, or state if it must be a noun, or an adjective.

Comment: Voting to close for being "off topic", as soon as the OP edits his answer, I'll gladly retract it.

Comment: **experience**?

Answer (score 4):

***[Edifying](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/edifying)***  may suggest that connotation:

> - providing moral or intellectual instruction:
>     *edifying literature* (ODO)

Comment: All things are lawful for me, but all things are not expedient. All things are lawful for me, but all things *edify* not.

Answer (score -1):

This option is not likely to be popular, but **philosophy** is something which improves us both intellectually and morally:

> 1. (Philosophy) the academic discipline concerned with making explicit the nature and significance of ordinary and scientific beliefs and investigating the intelligibility of concepts by means of rational argument concerning their presuppositions, implications, and interrelationships; in particular, the rational investigation of the nature and structure of reality (metaphysics), the resources and limits of knowledge (epistemology), the principles and import of moral judgment (ethics), and the relationship between language and reality (semantics)

(philosophy. (n.d.) Collins English Dictionary – Complete and Unabridged. (1991, 1994, 1998, 2000, 2003). Retrieved September 11 2015 from http://www.thefreedictionary.com/philosophy).